# Preparation work before executing the app Plesk NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, plesk

I'm trying to deploy an Api Rest that was build on NodeJS Express and when I try to make the deploy process, I got this error. I don't know hoy can I solve this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are importing some modules in your app.js with the import function, but you can't do that because you are stating in your config to treat your js files as module, to import external modules inside ES modules you should use the following structure:

"import { something } from /path/to/module"

Let me know if it solved your problem!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. if for example I have the import like this:

"import { config } from "dotenv" "

How can I import using the correct structure?

Comment: I will wait for your answer

Comment: Hey? Can you please help me?

Comment: could you share some of your code files to have a better understanding of the problem?

Comment: Sure, this is my index.js.

` import express from "express";

import routes from "./api/routes/routes.js";
const app = express();

app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

app.use("/api", routes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running in port ${PORT}`));`

Comment: The thing is it's supposed to be working cause node 16+ support modules, no?

Comment: well, seeing your code now i dont think there's an issue with it, maybe your versions are not compatible or need to be updated, but cant help you with this little information.
I would suggest you update your question with all the details of your use case.